# How to Fix "Variable Lengths Differ" Error in r When Doing a Linear Regression

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lm

I'm trying to make a for loop that loops through my data frame and runs a linear regression of all columns against `AcquisitionTime` which is a double. All columns are of the same length. Eventually I want to just use one of the apply functions instead of the for loop to do this but I am really new at r and the apply functions don't make sense to me.

```
##pdf("ROIs_vs_AcquisitionTime_lm.pdf")
x = 0
for (i in names(raw_data)){
  if(x > 9){
    fit <- lm(i ~ AcquisitionTimes, data = raw_data)
    ##print(ggplotRegression(fit))
  }
  x <- x + 1
}
##dev.off()
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = i ~ AcquisitionTimes, data = raw_data,:  
variable lengths differ (found for 'AcquisitionTimes')
```

What is causing this error? I checked to see if I had any other data frames named raw_data, but I did not. I even cleared the objects in R to see if that would help. Everywhere I read says that this is either because the variable `AcquisitionTimes` does not exist in the data frame or because there are identical variable names somewhere in my data. So far I haven't found any.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Ok, I'll edit it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Chriscross We actually encourage you to use `dput()` for sharing data instead of links, but don't worry about it this time.

Comment: One problem I can see is with: lm(i ~ AcquisitionTimes, data = raw_data). The reason this doesn't work is because `i` is a string here, different from the format of the rest of the formula. You may be able to fix this by doing: `lm(paste(i, "~ AcquisitionTimes"), data = raw_data)`.

Comment: I don't think you can just use `i` in the formula to loop through. Formulas use nonstandard evalution so it's taking the `i` literally as a variable called `i` rather than looping through your `i` as a looping variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have mentioned the fix already in my comment but the following simple example can reproduce your error:

```
data(iris)
i = "Sepal.Length"
lm(i ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
```

You will see

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = i ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'Sepal.Width')
```

To correct this, we can instead do:

```
lm(paste(i , "~ Sepal.Width"), data = iris)
```

which works as expected:

```
Call:
lm(formula = paste(i, "~ Sepal.Width"), data = iris)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     6.5262      -0.2234
```

In your case, it will be

```
lm(paste(i, "~ AcquisitionTimes"), data = raw_data)
```

Comment: I found that this works for `lm()` function, but in another case I'm using the `lm_lin()` function from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/estimatr/versions/0.30.2/topics/lm_lin

In this case, using the paste method, I get a new error: `Error: 'x' must be a formula` Any ideas on how to address this similar use case?

Comment: @alxlvt, please do instead `lm_lin(as.formula(paste(i, "~ AcquisitionTimes")), ...)`. In this case, I wrap the paste in as.formula to ensure it is passed as a formula to the `lm_lin` function